# Initiate image download using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my users to be able to download images from my website using jQuery. For example, I have an image like this below on my website. When user clicks "Download" button that image must be downloaded to user system. What can I do to achieve this?

```
<div class="download"><img src="http://m.com/hello.png"><div>
```

EDIT : PHP code is also welcome, for example `download.php?url=http://m.com/hello.png`,

PS: http://m.com/hello.png is an external URL.

Comment: Is using PHP acceptable?

Comment: yea :) but jquery will be easier

Comment: As far as I know, its only possible on client side using an IE solution. Otherwise you will have to do it on the serverside

Comment: Ok can some one say php code

Comment: I found this article on stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666381/image-onclick-download-image-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 3):

For server side, you could direct the image click to a PHP page that would force the download.

On your HTML page, you would have:

If PNG file

`<a href="download.php?ext=png"><img src="hello.png" /></a>`

or if JPG file

`<a href="download.php?ext=jpg"><img src="hello.jpg" /></a>`

Then a PHP page `download.php` as shown below

```
<?php
if($_GET['ext'] == 'png') {
    $ext = 'png';
} elseif($_GET['ext'] == 'jpg') {
    $ext = 'jpg';
}

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Name-of-Image.'.$ext);
header('Content-type: image/'.$ext);
readfile('http://m.com/hello.'.$ext);

?>
```

Comment: i think this code is for internal image..can i know code for external url

Comment: Hey thanks its working.how to differentiate between png and jpg image ?

Comment: Just change the `png` in the code to `jpg`. Please mark as the correct answer also :)

Comment: i mean , single download.php , that detects png or jpg

Comment: Updated answer to base file extension on parameter set by HTML link.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.png"');
readfile('hello.png');
```

Comment: you mean external image URL?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801471/download-image-from-url-using-php-code

Comment: For user system, not to server

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do it reliably without using PHP. I found a previous question on this website that can assist you with this: [Force Download an Image Using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796974/force-download-an-image-using-javascript)

*Actually there is a method that relies on HTML5 in there, but I'm not quite sure you could consider that reliable yet.*